# не могу вывести субменю горизонтального меню на экран

Tags: html, css, css3, flexbox

В div-е `nav` (навигационный панель) есть субменю, которое скрыто при загрузке сайта(`top:-9999em;`), но она не выводится на экран при наведении курсора на элемент меню.

Пишу:

```
   .nav_main_ul li a:hover .submenu{
         top:150;
 }
```

но не выводится.

Всё правильно работало до того момента пока `position(relative, absolute)` не поменял на `flexbox`.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  list-style:none;
}
 html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#nav{
  left:0; top:120px;
  background-color: #00004d;
    width: 100%;
}
.nav_main_ul{
  position:relative;
    margin: 0px 0 0 400px;
}
#nav ul{
  height:50px;
  list-style:none;
  background-color: #00004d;
}
#nav li{
  display:block;
  float:left;
  font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size:20px;
  position:relative;
}
#nav li a{
  color:#fff;
  display:block;
  height:50px;
  padding:0 10px;
  text-decoration:none;
  line-height:50px;
}
.nav_main_ul li a:hover{
  background:#000080;
}
/*.nav_main_ul li a:hover .submenu{
  top:50;
}*/
.submenu{
  position:absolute;
  width:250px;
  top:-9999em;
}
.submenu li{
  width:100%;
  height:40px;
  background:#00004d;
}
.submenu li a{
  line-height:50px;
  height:50px;
  transition: background 0.5s;
}
.submenu li a:hover{
  background-color:red;
}
li:hover .submenu li{
  display:block;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <ul class="nav_main_ul">
    <li><a href="">Main</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
    <li> <a href="#">News</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">link 5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link 6</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link 7</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link 8</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
    <li><a href="#">About us</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">link 5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link 6</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link 7</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link 8</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link 9</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link 10</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Gallery</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">link 5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link 6</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link 7</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link 8</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link 9</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link 10</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contacts</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">link 5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link 6</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link 7</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link 8</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link 9</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link 10</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.submenu{
  position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0; /* позиционируем относительно родителя, у которого стоит position relative */
  display: none;  /* скрывам меню */
}
.nav_main_ul li:hover .submenu{
    display: block; /* при наведении на li - показваем соотв. submenu */
}
```

Пример

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#nav {
  left: 0;
  top: 120px;
  background-color: #00004d;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav_main_ul {
  position: relative;  
}

#nav ul {
  height: 50px;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #00004d;  
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0; /* один из способов удаления отступов для child inline-block */
}

#nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

#nav li a {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.nav_main_ul li a:hover {
  background: #000080;
}

.submenu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}

.nav_main_ul li:hover .submenu {
  display: block;
}

.submenu li {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: #00004d;
}

.submenu li a {
  line-height: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transition: background 0.5s;
}

.submenu li a:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <ul class="nav_main_ul">
    <li><a href="">Main</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#">News</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">link 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 8</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About us</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">link 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 8</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 9</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 10</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">link 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 8</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 9</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 10</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contacts</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">link 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 8</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 9</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 10</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```